# Convolve working with Interpolated Functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, convolution, curvesmoothing

I'm using Mathematica 7.

I have an interpolated function, here's an example:

```
pressures = 
  WeatherData["Chicago", "Pressure", {2010, 8}] // 
     DeleteCases[#, {_, _Missing}] & // 
    Map[{AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &, #] & // Interpolation;
```

I'd like to compute it's derivative, which is straight forward:

```
dpressures = D[pressures[x], x]
```

Now, If you plot this funciton

```
Plot[3600*dpressures, {x, AbsoluteTime[{2010, 8, 2}], AbsoluteTime[{2010, 8, 30}]}]
```

(sorry, don't know how to post the image from within Mathematica, and don't have time to figure it out.) You'll find that it's *very* noisy.  So, I'd like to smooth it out.  My first thought was to use Convolve, and integrate it against a Gaussian kernel, something like the following:

```
a = Convolve[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 5], x], 3600*dpressures, x, y]
```

Returns

```
360 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Convolve[E^(-(x^2/50)), InterpolatingFunction[{{3.48961266 10^9, 3.49228746 10^9}},<>], ][x], x, y]
```

Which looks reasonable to me.  Unfortunately, I believe I have made a mistake somewhere, because the result I get back does not seem to be evaluatable.  That is:

```
a /. y -> AbsoluteTime[{2010, 8, 2}]
```

Returns

```
360 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Convolve[E^(-(x^2/50)), InterpolatingFunction[{{3.48961266 10^9, 3.49228746 10^9}},<>][x], x, 3489696000]]
```

Which just ain't what I was looking for I'm expecting a number between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convolve seeks a closed form for the convolution. You could try a numerical convolution, starting with something like

```
NConvolve[f_, g_, x_, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f (g /. x -> y - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

However, for this noisy non-smooth function the numerical integration will struggle. (It won't work with default settings, and would be slow even with carefully chosen settings.)

I suggest you operate directly on the underlying data instead of interpolating the noisy data.

The bounds of your time range:

```
In[89]:= {lower = Min[First[pressures]], upper = Max[First[pressures]]}    
Out[89]= {3.48961*10^9, 3.49229*10^9}
```

Use your interpolation to get samples every hour*:

```
data = Table[pressures[x], {x, lower, upper, 3600}];
```

Now compare

```
ListLinePlot[Differences[data]]
```

with smoothed version over 5 hour window:

```
ListLinePlot[GaussianFilter[Differences[data], 5]]
```

- You may want to use InterpolationOrder -> 1 for noisy data.